# Add enum item to type - Specman

Tags: types, enumeration, extend, specman

I have: `type color : [ blue = 1, white = 2];`
I want to extend this type and add:
black=0
how should I do that?
thanks,

Answer (score 1):

you can extend the type -

```
extend color : [ black =  0];
```